# Extracting data from sql table by comparing data from a List

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a List of IDS say 1,2,4,6 in my LIST (C#) what i need to do is extract data corresponding to these IDS from my table **Connections**

[image]

My LIST code is the following:

```
string str = "SELECT id1 FROM [Example] WHERE id2 = '1' UNION SELECT id2 FROM Example WHERE id1 = '1'";
            ds = new DataSet(str);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
            da.Fill(ds);
            //GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            //GridView1.DataBind();
            DataTable dtDetails = ds.Tables[0];
            List<int> lst =
                                (from dr in dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
                                 select Convert.ToInt32(dr["id1"])).ToList<int>();
```

What the above code does is retrieve the no's 2 3 4 6 in the LIST

**What i want to do is retrieve id2 corresponding to these no's that's it ?**

Edit:

```
 string str = "SELECT id1 FROM [Example] WHERE id2 = '1' UNION SELECT id2 FROM Example WHERE id1 = '1'";
        ds = new DataSet(str);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(str, con);
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dtDetails = ds.Tables[0];
        List<int> lst =
                            (from dr in dtDetails.AsEnumerable()
                             select Convert.ToInt32(dr["id1"])).ToList<int>();

        foreach (int prime in lst) // Loop through List with foreach
        {

             str1 = " SELECT id2 FROM [Connections] where id2= '"+prime+"'";
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(str1, con);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(str1, con);
            da1.Fill(ds1);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

> **My gridview is not displaying anything**

Comment: Sorry, I am confused; what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TRY THiS!

SELECT id2 FROM Example WHERE id2 IN( SELECT id1 FROM [Example] WHERE id2 = '1' UNION SELECT id2 FROM Example WHERE id1 = '1')

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is use IN as part of your select. So the select statement sent to SQL Server could be:

SELECT * FROM [Connections] where id1 IN (1, 2, 4, 6)

In psudo code this would be:

string list = "1, 2, 4, 6";
string str1 = "SELECT * FROM [Connections] where id1 IN(" + list + ")";

Of course in your code you would construct list from your List of IDs

Comment: It still gives me the same result as before its only displaying data corresponding to '6'

Comment: anyway i got my answer the result i wanted